# How to permanently set priority for network interfaces in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, network-interface

This is Ubuntu 18.04.
I have two network interfaces (wwan0 and wlan0) and I want to know if there's a way to set the priority of wlan0 if both are available.

Now I've found out about setting the metric values for each interface and I can manually set the metrics for each one and it does work. So if both are available and I'm connected to wwan0, I can run `sudo ifmetric wwan0 600 && sudo ifmetric wlan0 0` and after that, it works as expected I.e. I'm connected with wlan0, instead of wwan0.

But when I disconnect to wifi, the metric value for wlan0 resets back to 600 (the default value I assume). Is there a way to make this change permanent for both interfaces?

I'll leave the steps I took to try to make it more clear.

Running `route -n` first:

metric 600 for wlan0 and metric 0 for wwan0... So wwan0 is preferred

`ip route`command shows wwan0 above wlan0

Then I `sudo ifmetric wwan0 600 && sudo ifmetric wlan0` to swap priorities

I confirm metrics have changed and again do `ip route` and wlan0 is above wwan0.

So problem now is, if I turn off wifi and turn it back on, the metric for wlan0 goes back to 600, and `route -n` shows wwan0 above wlan0.

Is there a way for me to make this change permanent and/or any other kind of solution/tool to allow me to permanently set the priority for the wlan0 interface over any other?

Thank you.